# How do 4-20 mA transducers work?

Tags: sensor, signal, current-measurement, transducer, instrumentation

I am quite new to the instrumentation of electronics. I have noticed that most transducers that are used in the industry only use 2 pins, where it is usually marked with a positive 24V pin and an output pin (specifically 4-20mA.) I assume that the sensor works as a variable resistor that adjusts the signal between 4-20mA.

Is that pin connected through an ammeter on the PLC side and through to the ground of the PLC?

What is the industry standard with regard to the output of the sensor current or voltage?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop Also see links at bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensor has a current output that will output 4-20 mA and the ammeter in the PLC will measure it.

If you connect a resistor from the sensor output to ground you can measure the voltage over the resistor with a multimeter or PLC voltage input. That is essentially how the ammeter in the PLC works too.

It depends on the sensor how high of a voltage it can produce to generate the output current. If the sensor maximum output is 10 volts, the maximum resistor you can place in series is 500 ohms. That would convert the 4-20 mA current signal to 2-10 V voltage signal.

Currents between 0-4 mA can be used to indicate a fault. 0 mA would indicate that the connection is cut. 1 mA could be used to indicate some different error state.